# Dataflow: Multiple Fanout / Combination of N Arrays

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Say I have a data `key1 = [1, 2, 3] and key2 = [a, b, c]` where a and b are key value where value is an array. I need to flatMap this and produce `[1,a], [2, a], [3, a], [1, b], [2, b], [3, b], [1, c], [2, c], [3, c]`. What is the best way to achieve this in Dataflow if we were to create multi-level fanout (in other words, n way combination of arrays)?

Note: example is just over two arrays so I can do flatmap with map, but this need to handle n array combinations.

Comment: This looks like a cartesian product operation. Is this correct? Is `[1, 2, 3]` an element in a PCollection, or is it a PCollection itself?

Comment: @Pablo Yes, is there an optimum support for this?

Comment: Is [1, 2, 3] an element in a PCollection, or is it a PCollection itself?

Comment: @Pablo Is an element in PCollection, so we may have something like PCollection[Tuple[Array[Integer], Array[Character]] where I want to produce PCollection[Integer+Character] where Integer + Character is combination of two arrays in Tuple so we are fanning out. Also it is important to note that we have a high fanout (1.5k elements) from this combination per element in PCollection.